# advice-add FOR function dired-do-copy

Tags: dired, advice, arguments

I got a problem for an `advice-add` inside Dired's copy function (`dired-do-copy`).
My object is it to filter all marked files/directories in Dired, which should be copied to an other location within Dired. The filter is simply finding all files including a recursive search in marked directories which are greater in files size than a given treasure/limit value. Only the files, which are smaller in file size than this value should be copied by Dired in the normal way. The other greater one's I would like to copy by a separate function (not mentioned here) in an asynchronous process.

My problem is that the ordinary list, where all files are mentioned with its absolute path can not be given to the `dired-do-copy` function. Every time I copy within Dired with activated following `advice-add`

I get this error:

```
apply: Wrong number of arguments: (0 . 1), 2
```

Please see my `advice-add` function:

```
 (defun filter-files-*-marked-greater-than-*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH* (old-function  &rest arguments)

   ;; for testing and debugging
   (message "Here are all given arguments %S" arguments )

   (let* (
         (list-of-marked-files-first (dired-get-marked-files))
         (list-of-marked-files-second list-of-marked-files-first)
         (list-of-all-files-within-all-marked-directories nil)
         list-of-files-smaller-than-*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*
         list-of-all-marked-files-greater-than*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*
         number-of-marked-files
         singleFile
         singleFileOrDirectory
         fileSize
         fileSizeKB
         fileSizeMB
         numberOfFilesToCopy
         numberOfFilesToCopy-greater-than-*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*
         newArgsList
         )

     ;; filter all directories from marked list
     (while list-of-marked-files-first
       (setq singleFileOrDirectory (pop list-of-marked-files-first))
       ;; if a directory then recursivly collect all files inside this directory
       ;; and subdirectories and add them to
       ;; list-of-all-files-within-all-marked-directories
       ;; directory check follows --> first condition is also true if it is
       ;; a symlink (see file-attributes)
       (if (and (nth 0 (file-attributes singleFileOrDirectory)) (booleanp (nth 0 (file-attributes singleFileOrDirectory))))
          (progn
            (setq list-of-all-files-within-all-marked-directories (append list-of-all-files-within-all-marked-directories (directory-files-recursively singleFileOrDirectory ".*" t)))
            ;; delete the directory from the list-of-marked-files-second
            (delete singleFileOrDirectory list-of-marked-files-second))))
     ;; put these to lists together, where both have only files listed inside
     (setq list-of-marked-files-second (append list-of-marked-files-second list-of-all-files-within-all-marked-directories))
     ;; determine elements in list-of-marked-files-second, where only files and
     ;; no directories reside inside
     (setq number-of-marked-files (length list-of-marked-files-second))
     ;; true as long any marked files exist AND not more than one file was found,
     ;; which is larger than *LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*
     (while  list-of-marked-files-second
       (setq singleFile (pop list-of-marked-files-second))
       ;; check for directory is obsolete, because there shouldn't be any
       ;; directories inside
       (if (not (nth 0 (file-attributes singleFile)))
          (progn
            (setq fileSize (nth 7 (file-attributes singleFile)))
            (setq fileSizeKB (/ fileSize 1024))
            (setq fileSizeMB (/ fileSizeKB 1024))

            (if (> fileSizeMB *LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*)
            (progn
              (add-to-list 'list-of-all-marked-files-greater-than*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH* singleFile)
              ;; remove file greater than *LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH* from
              ;; given arguments in ordwer to copy it with rsync
              ;; (delete singleFile arguments)

              )
              (add-to-list 'list-of-files-smaller-than-*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH* singleFile)
              )
            )
        )
       )

     ;; for testing and debugging
     (setq  numberOfFilesToCopy-greater-than-*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH* (length list-of-all-marked-files-greater-than*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*))
     ;; for testing and debugging
     (setq numberOfFilesToCopy (length list-of-files-smaller-than-*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*))
     ;; for testing and debugging
     (setq numberOfArgsElements (length arguments))

     ;; for testing and debugging
     (if (sequencep arguments)
        (message (propertize (concat "arguments is sequencep" ".") 'face '(:foreground "cyan"))))

     ;; for testing and debugging
     (if (sequencep list-of-files-smaller-than-*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*)
        (message (propertize (concat "list-of-files-smaller-than-*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH* is sequencep" ".") 'face '(:foreground "cyan"))))



     ;; (while list-of-files-smaller-than-*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*
     ;;   (setq runner (pop list-of-files-smaller-than-*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*))
     ;;   (message (propertize runner 'face '(:foreground "cyan"))))

     ;; for testing and debugging
     (message "Here are all arguments end the end of advice-add function %S" arguments)

     ;; for testing and debugging
     (print arguments)


     ;; for testing and debugging
     (add-to-list 'newArgsList list-of-files-smaller-than-*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*)

     ;; testing: when directory is given for copying
     ;; for testing and debugging
     (message (propertize (concat (number-to-string numberOfFilesToCopy) " Number of arguments given to dired-do-copy ") 'face '(:foreground "cyan")))
     (message (propertize (concat (number-to-string numberOfFilesToCopy-greater-than-*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*) " Number of found files greater than 10MB.") 'face '(:foreground "cyan")))
     (message (propertize (concat (number-to-string numberOfArgsElements) " Number of elements in Args.") 'face '(:foreground "cyan")))

     ;; (setq arguments list-of-files-smaller-than-*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*)

     ;; !!!!!!!replacing
     ;; (apply old-function newArgsList)
     ;; (apply old-function )

     ;; with
     ;; (apply dired-do-copy newArgsList)
     ;; (apply dired-do-copy 'list-of-files-smaller-than-*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*)


     ;; !!!!!!!with following line do not work
     (apply old-function list-of-files-smaller-than-*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*)
     ;; !!!!!!!

     )
   )
```

And here my final `advice-add` declaration.

```
(advice-add 'dired-do-copy :around #'filter-files-*-marked-greater-than-*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*)
```

Comment: Please consider reformatting your code a bit, so the lines are not so long, requiring scrolling.)

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you use `apply` but the last arg you pass to it is not a *list of arguments* but a single argument which is a list of files.

IOW, if you want to pass that list of files as the first arg to the `old-function`, you should use `(funcall old-function list-of-files-smaller-than-*LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*)` (btw, I wonder why stopped at less than 60 chars for that variable name.  Memory is plentiful nowadays so you can use even much longer variable names).

But in any case, `dired-do-copy` does not accept a list of files as argument.  So you likely need to place your advice elsewhere, e.g. on `dired-copy-file`.

One more thing: please don't use `add-to-list` on local variables (it doesn't work in lexically scoped code), use `push` (if you know the element isn't already in the list) or `cl-pushnew` (from the `cl-lib` package bundled with Emacs) instead.

Answer (score 0):

@Stefan has answered your question about advice, but this might help you accomplish your aim in another way.

---

If you use [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then you can use command **`diredp-mark-sexp-recursive`**, bound to **`M-+ M-(`** and **`M-+ * (`** by default, to mark all files in the current directory, and all files in its marked subdirectories, and the same thing recursively, when those *files satisfy a condition* that you specify interactively.  This is a recursively acting version of standard Dired command `dired-mark-sexp` (which acts only in the current Dired listing, but which could contain inserted subdirs).

(All commands that act recursively on marked subdirs (or all subdirs) are on prefix key **`M-+`**.)

You are prompted for a Lisp sexp that specifies the condition to satisfy. In this case you would just enter this:

`(> size *LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*)`

or more probably this, if you don't want to also mark directories:

**`(and (not (file-directory-p name))  (> size *LIMIT-VALUE-COPYING-TRASH*))`**

That's not hard to do, but where `name` and `size` come from - what are they?  These are predefined variables for use with such commands.  Their values are taken from each file tested, in turn.  (See the doc string, below.)

The same command is menu item **If...** of submenu [**Here and Below**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus#MarksHereAndBelow) of menu-bar menu **Marks**.

`C-h f diredp-mark-sexp-recursive` says:

> **`diredp-mark-sexp-recursive`** is an interactive Lisp function in
>   [`dired+.el’.
>
> `(diredp-mark-sexp-recursive PREDICATE &optional ARG DETAILS)`
>
> Mark files here and below for which `PREDICATE` returns non-`nil`.
>
> Like `diredp-mark-sexp`’, but act recursively on subdirs.
>
> - A non-negative prefix arg means to unmark those files instead.
> - A non-positive prefix arg means to ignore subdir markings and act
>     instead on *ALL* subdirs.  That is, mark all in this directory and all
>     descendant directories.
>
> `PREDICATE` is a lisp sexp that can refer to the following symbols as
>   variables:
>
> - **`mode`**   [string]  file permission bits, e.g. `"-rw-r--r--"`
> - **nlink`**  [integer] number of links to file
> - **`size`**   [integer] file size in bytes
> - **`uid`**    [string]  owner
> - **`gid`**    [string]  group (If the gid is not displayed by `ls`,
>                        this will still be set (to the same as uid))
> - **`time`**   [string]  the time that `ls` displays, e.g. `"Feb 12 14:17"`
> - **`name`**   [string]  the name of the file
> - **`sym`**    [string]  if file is a symbolic link, the linked-to name,
>                        else `""`
> - **`inode`**  [integer] the inode of the file (only for `ls -i` output)
> - **`blks`**   [integer] the size of the file for `ls -s` output
>                        (ususally in blocks or, with `-k`, in Kbytes)
>
> *Examples:*
>
> - Mark zero-length files: `(equal 0 size)`
> - Mark files last modified on Feb 2: `(string-match "Feb  2" time)`
> - Mark uncompiled Emacs Lisp files (`.el`’ file without a `.elc` file):
>      First, Dired just the source files: `dired *.el`.
>      Then, use `M-x diredp-mark-sexp-recursive` with this sexp:
>           `(not (file-exists-p (concat name "c")))`
>
> There’s an ambiguity when a single integer not followed by a unit
>   prefix precedes the file mode: It is then parsed as inode number
>   and not as block size (this always works for GNU coreutils `ls`).
>
> Another limitation is that the uid field is needed for the
>   function to work correctly.  In particular, the field is not
>   present for some values of `ls-lisp-emulation`.
>
> This function operates only on the Dired buffer content.  It does not
>   refer at all to the underlying file system.  Contrast this with
>   `find-dired`, which might be preferable for the task at hand.
>
> When called from Lisp, `DETAILS` is passed to `diredp-get-subdirs`.